# BeautifulSoup, difference between soup() and soup.findAll()?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm confused about the difference between `soup('tag_name')` and `soup.find_all('tag_name')`.  Here is an example with a short bit of html:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

string = """
<html><body><div class="MsoNormal">
<span style='font-family: "Times New Roman","serif"; font-size: 12.0pt; 
line-height: 107%;'> Some text <o:p></o:p></span></div></body></html>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(string)
if soup('span') == soup.find_all('span'):
    print('No difference')
```

This example is small, but I've tested much longer strings and found no difference between the two.  I thought it might be new as of `bs4` but all I could see in the documentation is that `findAll` became `find_all`.  Are these two methods the same?  Is the first one actually a method?  When will they give different results?

Comment: Note: `soup.span` also works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no difference between the two.

From [the documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#calling-a-tag-is-like-calling-find-all): "*If you treat the BeautifulSoup object or a Tag object as though it were a function, then it’s the same as calling find_all() on that object.*"

Answer (score 1):

-> "soup()" is primarily used for finding elements by their tag name. It's a shorthand notation for soup.find_all(tag_name).

-> "soup.findAll()" is more versatile and allows you to specify various filters, such as tag name, attributes, text content, etc., to find elements that match specific criterias.

Comment: In newer code avoid old syntax `findAll()` instead use `find_all()` or `select()` with `css selectors` - For more take a minute to [check docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#method-names)